# Qlikview guage chart - static variable

Tags: qlikview

I am looking to create and use a gauge chart, but I am trying to figure how to compare selected vs the complete universe.   For example, let's say I want to measure a monthly spending average of one department vs. the spending average of the entire organization.  How do I make the organization average the segment marker?  or make it a static variable that does not change with the selection?

Answer (score 1):

As is the case with a lot of questions that pop up here, you can use set analysis to achieve this. In you gauge expression you could do something like this:

Assuming you are going to select one or more departments in the current state, you could do

```
percent_of_total_spending = avg({$}spending)/avg({1}spending)
```

The `{}` syntax is used in conjunction with the set identifiers `$` and `1` to denote the the set of the current selections and the entire universe respectively. So the above expression will give you the percentage of average organizational spending for whatever departments you have selected.

You can use set modifiers in addition to the set identifiers to further customize what population you are including.  See [here](http://hyunkucho.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/qlikview-set-analysis/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use set analysis and tell the expression what to ignore in the selections box.

Example:

```
Sum({<Month=, Year=>}Spending)
```

What the above is telling you is that it's taking the "Month" field and setting the selection for that specific expression to nothing, as well as the "Year" field. If you were to do the following:

```
Sum({<Month=, Year={"2014"}>}Spending)
```

It will calculate for that specific year, or even this

```
Sum({<Month=, Year={"2013","2014"}>}Spending)
```

Will make it calculate for both 2013 and 2014. Read up on the helpfile as well by pushing F1 and searching for set analysis.

So something like this will work for you

```
Sum(Spending) / Sum({<Month=, Year=>}Spending)
```